# JAXB: Unmarshaling of abstract bound generic Type fails

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

I ran into an issue about unmarshalling an XML-file using JAXB, if the matching Java-Class uses a generic type bound to an *abstract* class.

I already filed a bugreport on this behaviour ([java.net/jira](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1103)), but baybe I'm missing something or someone has an Idea to get around this Problem? So here's my Problem:

In the following example, I need a boundary for any type of Number, but JAXB tries to unmarshal this by instantiating to Number, which is abstract.
Ommitting the boundary or changing it to an instantiable type (like Object) solves the issue, but weakens the generics.

The following example shows this, see the included comment. Removing the comment deactivating the type-boundary, this program will fail.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JaxbTester {

  /*
   * AbstractContainer<T> -> works, but misses boundaries
   * AbstractContainer<T extends Object> -> works, but boundaries are too large
   * AbstractContainer<T extends Number> -> fails: "Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unable to create an instance of java.lang.Number"
   */
  static abstract class AbstractContainer<T /* extends Number */> {

    @XmlElement
    T someNumber;

  }

  @XmlRootElement
  static class ContainerImpl<T extends Number> extends AbstractContainer<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ContainerImpl() {
      // for JAXB
    }

    public ContainerImpl(final T someNumber) {
      this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }

  }

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final AbstractContainer<Double> containerA = new ContainerImpl<>(42.5);

    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContainerImpl.class);

    final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    marshaller.marshal(containerA, stringWriter);
    final String xmlString = stringWriter.toString();

    System.out.println(xmlString);

    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(event -> {
      System.err.println("!! " + event.getMessage() + " - " + event.getLocator() + "\n");
      return true;
    });

    final Object unmarshal = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
    System.out.println("unmarshal: " + unmarshal.toString());
  }

}
```

Any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across a possible solution (let's call it 'workaround') for my problem:

Change `@XmlElement T someNumber;` to `@XmlElement(type = Object.class) T someNumber;`. This gives JAXB the total freedom of the instantiable Object-Class... Actually, the returned Value-Object is of type `Double`, so internally the conversion seems to work... Apart from having to annotate each field - any other caveats to this?

Comment: Is this an actual solution or are you asking if this is the solution.  If it is the latter, put this into your original question as an edit instead of posting it as an answer.

Comment: it is a working solution, but in my eyes maybe not the best - for me, it feels like a workaround...